# Android WebView Activity Toolbar

Tags: android, android-webview, android-toolbar

In my app, I have a WebView Activity that loads a URL.

I have a custom Toolbar, and I want it to show the title of the page, the URL and if it is a secure connection or not.

I have observed that several famous apps (Twitter, Youtube, Telegram...) have this exactly same Toolbar model for their WebView activities, and I wonder if Android has a default toolbar for this, or if they have built the same custom toolbar.

And, if it is the second case (I have to build the custom toolbar myself), I can access the page title overriding the onPageFinished method of the WebViewClient, but how can I get if the connection is secure or not?

I include a snapshot of the Telegram toolbar I am talking about (it is the same for the other apps):

[image]

Thank you very much and sorry about my English!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show web url in this kind of view, you don't need WebViewActivity.

This can be achieved using Chrome's custom tabs.

To achieve this, follow these steps:
(1) add dependency in your `build.gradle` -> `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'`

(2) write this method in some some utility class

```
    public static void openUrlInChromeCustomTab(Context context, String url) {
    try {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(url));
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // might not available.
        //openUrlLinkInWebView(context, url);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(3) call this method from where you want to open link like : `openUrlInChromeCustomTab(activity, url");`

that's all.

Also, you can customise it with whatever you needs. learn more at https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.
I thought all those apps use a WebView Activity, but they use this library instead.

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly was looking for this!!...thanks!!